# Prototype Events: Use Input Value From When Event is Created

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, dom-events

I have recently read how to do this but cannot for the life of me find it again!

Basically, I'm creating some events that listen to form inputs and update their values when triggered. How do I pass the initial input value (the value of the input when the event is created) to the event so that I can compare it with the current value?

Answer (score 3):

Just store it in a variable outside the event handling closure, like this:

```
var original = $('someinput').getValue();
$('someinput').observe('whatever_event', function(ev) {
    $('someinput').getValue(); // contains current value
    original; // contains original value
});
```

UPDATE: Replaced the above code with Prototype. jQuery version below for reference.

```
var original = $('#someinput').val();
$('#someinput').whatever_event(function(ev) {
    this.val(); // contains current value
    original; // contains original value
});
```

Comment: For good measure I would store `$('#someinput')` in a variable.

Comment: That looks like jQuery, not Prototype :-)

Comment: @Pointy -- Oops, my fault -- I'm so used to jQuery questions nowadays. I updated the post to include the Prototype version too.

Comment: If you want to use it for a variety of controls, you could use prototype's `getValue` instead of `value`: http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Form/Element/getValue/

Answer (score 0):

The DOM already stores that value for you (for `input` types, not `select`).

```
element.observe('click', function(){
    // In this context, this == element
    if (this.defaultValue != this.value) {
        // value is different
    }
}
```